# UIColor Made of Variables

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uicolor

I'm trying to make a Swift application in iOS that has three sliders, one for each red, green, and blue.  Each time a slider is moved the current value is assigned to a variable.  My problem is that I would like to set the background color to the variables that were set.  The syntax that I'm familiar with is,

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

So what I'm trying to do in my head looks like,

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: returnedValueOfRedSlider/255.0, green: returnedValueOfGreenSlider/255.0, blue: returnedValueOfBlueSlider/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

but it has been made apparent that this is a big no no.  So what can I do to use variables to make a UIColor to assign to the backgroundColor?

Thank you,

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is that "a big no no"?

Comment: Is the problem just one of casting the numbers returned from the sliders to floats? Remember that Swift won't do this sort of conversion automatically.

Comment: Gary - I don't believe so.  It should be able to accept an Int because the default syntax looks like
   view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100/255.0, (and so on) )

Comment: Swift treats integer literals differently from integer instances. Literals can be converted seamlessly to essentially any numeric type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clean / readable, why not something like:

```
let red   = CGFloat(returnedValueOfRedSlider/255)
let green = CGFloat(returnedValueOfGreenSlider/255)
let blue  = CGFloat(returnedValueOfBlueSlider/255)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nate!  I had no idea that you had to convert the Int into CGFloats.  Thank you again!

Comment: @JackVaughn, accept Nate's answer by ticking the hollow checkmark next to his answer to turn it green.

Comment: @JackVaughn, if you command-click on a type (like `UIColor`), you'll see the Swift version of its header declaration. That will tell you what types it's expecting for each argument, which can help get to the bottom of cryptic compiler messages.

Comment: Also, if you type just `UIColor(` the command completion will show you the types as well.

Comment: @vacawama, thank you!  This is my first time using asking a question in a forum.  I can normally find what I'm looking for from previous posts, but thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your arguments into CGFloats.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(
    red: CGFloat(returnedValueOfRedSlider/255.0),
    green: CGFloat(returnedValueOfGreenSlider/255.0),
    blue: CGFloat(returnedValueOfBlueSlider/255.0),
    alpha: 1.0)
```